# data type mismatch error in criteria expression-ms access

Tags: ms-access

I am using the following query:

```
select Containers.SalesOrderNumber,
    GetWeightInMT(Sum([NetWeight]), WeightUOM) as Expr1,
    CInt(Round(GetWeightInMT(Sum([NetWeight]), WeightUOM), 0)) as WtMt,
    SalesOrders.CustomerID,
    SalesOrders.SalesOrderID,
    SalesOrders.UnitPrice,
    SalesOrders.Quantity,
    SalesOrders.SalesCommission,
    SalesOrders.LatestShipDate,
    SalesOrders.PortOfDischarge,
    SalesOrders.PlaceOfDelivery,
    SalesOrders.LowerTolerancePct,
    SalesOrders.UpperTolerancePct,
    SalesOrders.Grade,
    (SalesOrders.Quantity - WtMt) as OpenQty
from Containers
inner join SalesOrders on Containers.SalesOrderNumber = SalesOrders.SalesOrderNumber
group by Containers.SalesOrderNumber,
    Containers.WeightUOM,
    SalesOrders.CustomerID,
    SalesOrders.SalesOrderID,
    SalesOrders.UnitPrice,
    SalesOrders.Quantity,
    SalesOrders.SalesCommission,
    SalesOrders.LatestShipDate,
    SalesOrders.PortOfDischarge,
    SalesOrders.PlaceOfDelivery,
    SalesOrders.LowerTolerancePct,
    SalesOrders.UpperTolerancePct,
    SalesOrders.Grade;
```

and then calculate the sum of "OpenQty" in my textbox.
However i get error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".
Please help.
Thankyou

Comment: Possibly the GetWeightInMT() function is returning an empty string value, in which case the Round() function will generate that error.

Comment: the GetWeightInMT() does return value.the OpenQty values are positive and negative.Is it because of that??

Comment: If the function always returns a number type or even a string that can be treated like number by Round(), such as "1" or "-1", then should not be error. Without directly analyzing project and debugging, that's all I can offer as possible cause.

Comment: ok. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a calculated field (in this case `WtMt`) as part of the calculation of another field. You have to re-use the entire calculation.

```
(SalesOrders.Quantity - WtMt) as OpenQty
```

to

```
(SalesOrders.Quantity - CInt(Round(GetWeightInMT(Sum([NetWeight]), WeightUOM), 0))) as OpenQty
```

That however may not be the only problem. I recommend running our query for one calculated field at a time to see which one actually gives you the error.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to refer to calculated fields in another calculated field, just tested to confirm that. What you can't do is reference a calculated field in WHERE or HAVING clause in the same query. And I am not talking about table level Calculated type field.

Comment: thank you all for the help.It turns out that i was using the wrong field for calculation.

Comment: Buggers! I should have thought of that. Glad you found solution.